# Creating a Project with Pocketsphinx in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I followed this tutorial: https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/#initialization and builded up these 2 Files in VS.

Now i want to use the library in my project but I don't know how to bind it in Visual Studio.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe a few more details might be needed - the tutorial you linked leads to C++ code, are you trying to reference the DLL it builds into (COM), or simply add the code files to your existing project? Is your project in Visual Studio also C++? It becomes more complicated if it's .NET (C#).

Comment: I've never done somthing like this, so I am not sure which one would be better. My Project would be in C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding C++ DLL's to a C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889392/adding-c-dlls-to-a-c-sharp-project)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've successfully compiled the C++ items into a single library file (DLL), you can reference the DLL in another project in Visual Studio using the [Add Reference Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx).

**Be warned however,** by doing so you're now mixing different 'technologies', and may run into issues. You may find it difficult to use the library you've just referenced, as you can see in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889392/adding-c-dlls-to-a-c-sharp-project).

I would recommend to actually stick with C++, since the original files you started with in this library are C++. You can easily program C++ in Visual Studio as well (just create C++ project that's appropriate to your solution). You can also create a separate project in your solution to house these other files you've created externally, and VS will build/compile them for you as well.

In summary, try creating a new solution in  Visual Studio with two projects:

1. A C++ library project to house your C++ files already made
2. A C++ application (of whatever type) that will use the C++ library just made.

If you follow my recommendation, you can use the Add Reference option previously stated above to add the library reference (#1) to the application project (#2) as a "Project Reference."

Regardless, you may want to take some free courses on C++ and Visual Studio to get you more familiar with the environment. Pluralsight, Lynda, are just a few I can name off the top of my head. Good luck!

Comment: Now my project is in C++ but i still can't import the librarys. Can you explain me how can i Import the Pocketsphinx library into Visual Studio/ my project. If i want to import the DLL.. i get this error:A reference to ".." could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: If you have the original files that were compiled to make that DLL I recommend just putting those into a separate project in Visual Studio (within the same Solution) and reference the library as a project reference. Also, please refer to the comments above... this site isn't really meant to be a tutorial site in the Q&A section :)